# ASP.net: Searching for all validation controls on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, controls, webforms

I want to search an ASP.net form for all types of validation controls and programmatically add some attributes to them such as ForeColor.  Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Cheers and thanks Stackers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may get to something using the method [Page.GetValidators()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getvalidators.aspx)

It returns a collection of [IValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ivalidator.aspx) so you would need to cast it to the appropriate class

[Here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070614.htm) you have a sample usage.

Answer (score 1):

That turned out to be easier than I first thought thanks to Claudio's tips:

```
    foreach (IValidator cValidator in Page.GetValidators(null))
    {
        BaseValidator bv = (cValidator as BaseValidator);
        bv.CssClass = "Error";
        bv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        bv.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
    }
```

Thanks!